# Reasons to not throw when implementing `IComparable<T>`?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, nullable, icomparable

Are there any arguments against throwing inside the implementation of `IComparable<T>.CompareTo(T value)` ?

Does it make sense that `Nullable<T>.Compare(null, notNullValue)` doesn't throw and why ?

Comment: throw what? exception ?

Comment: We're talking about `null`s, right? Well, as of C# 8, instead of `throw`ing, just add a `where T: notnull` constraint on your type that implements `IComparable<T>`

Comment: The important thing about `IComparable` is that you follow the rules. They can be summed up roughly as "follow the trichotomy law of order" (if A<B and B<C, then A<C) and "be consistent" (if A<B, then it's always less than B and if B=D, then they are always equal and A<D). I would be very surprised if a comparison threw, but not surprised if `null` sorted less than any other value.  Also, remember that `null=null` in C# (unlike SQL)

Comment: Throwing on null in a `IComparable.CompareTo` is like leaving a big undocumented gotcha to your work mates in your code IMO

Comment: @TheGeneral care to elaborate more maybe with an example ?

Comment: @CoolBots super cool find, however i'm more concerned with types that i want to be nullable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons for not throwing are that it's not needed and that the signature of [IComparable.CompareTo(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't specify any exceptions, so you'd break the contract.

(BTW. [IComparable.CompareTo(Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) does allow `ArgumentExecption`).

---

> Does it make sense that Nullable.Compare(null, notNullValue) doesn't throw and why ?

Yes it makes sense not to throw, as `null` value has its place in the order of things. For example if you have a nullable column in the database you can still order it. In [SELECT - ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017) you can read:

> ASC | DESC
>
> Specifies that the values in the specified column should be sorted in ascending or descending order. ASC sorts from the lowest value to highest value. DESC sorts from highest value to lowest value. ASC is the default sort order. **Null values are treated as the lowest possible values.** [emphasis mine]

Comment: Shouldn't the meaning of Null or something of an undefined value be a domain concern rather than defaulting to a framework or SQL standard ?